# Get controls from another process using C#

Tags: c#

I have Window with some controls, and i want to send some event to them from my application.
So i have two problem:

- How to get controls from another application
- How invoke some event  into controls

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't provide a good answer using managed C# code.
What I can suggest is to use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/)

- directly (you can generate a script and compile it in an EXE)
- using AutoItX (COM object exposed by AutoIt) from C#

Hope this helps...

Comment: I'll answer you but, unfortunately, after weekends, problem with work machine

Comment: Thank you, @Marco. I want to use only .net, but this help me.